# OpenCL using uchar* instead of image2d_t

Tags: opencl

First of all... I am no expert in OpenCL.

I am using 2 kernels. The output of the first kernel is image2d_t but the input of the second kernel is " __global const uchar* source".

```
__kernel void firstKernel(__read_only  image2d_t input, __write_only image2d_t output)
{...}

__kernel void secondKernel( __global const uchar* source,...)
{...}
```

How to use the second kernel with that input?

Comment: Can you either modify the output of one, or the input of the other?

Comment: The really short answer is that you can't. You would need to use clEnqueueReadImage to copy from the image back to a buffer before passing to the second kernel

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it using the [`cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_Ext.html#cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer) assuming your implementation supports it.

My understanding is you first create the buffer (bearing in mind alignment etc requirements of images), then create the image from the buffer using the extension's functionality. Usual rules about read and write access and synchronisation will apply.